# How Java enum switch case and namespace import works

Tags: java

I am a little confused about the Java import system (I am not sure it is about Java import or this library - I use Apache POI 3.17):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(
                    "workbook.xls"));
            Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            for (Row row : sheet1) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    // Alternatively, get the value and format it yourself
                    switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
                    ///////////////// Why this is not CellType.STRING
                    case STRING:
                        System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue()
                                .getString());
                        break;
                    case NUMERIC:
                        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                            System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        }
                        break;
                    case BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case FORMULA:
                        System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
                        break;
                    case BLANK:
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

From the import section, you can see I did not import:

**import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;**

Why does this code work in that switch section? In each case I only use an enum type there (like `STRING` but not `CellType.STRING`). **How does the Java compiler know where those types come from?** I edit the code in Eclipse and when I hover over that "case STRING", it shows org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.STRING?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [JLS, Section 14.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11), says:

> If the type of the `switch` statement's Expression is an enum type, then every `case` constant associated with the `switch` statement must be an `enum` constant of that type.

The compiler only requires a simple name, because it already knows what type it needs to be.

> *SwitchLabel*:
>
> case *ConstantExpression* :
>
> case *EnumConstantName* :
>
> default :
>
> *EnumConstantName*:
>
> *Identifier*

And an `Identifier` is a simple name without `.`.

But this is a different concept from importing packages.  Importing isn't the mechanism that allows a type to be used; it's not like not importing a package disallows the use of that package.  After all, one can always use the fully qualified name of a type without importing it, e.g.

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType cellType = cell.getCellTypeEnum();
```

Importing packages is a convenience for us as programmers so that we don't need to type the fully qualified type name every time we need to reference the type; we just need to type the simple name.

The [JLS, Section 7.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5), states:

> An *import* declaration allows a named type or a `static` member to be referred to by a simple name (§6.2) that consists of a single identifier.
>
> Without the use of an appropriate import declaration, the only way to refer to a type declared in another package, or a `static` member of another type, is to use a fully qualified name (§6.7).

Importing a package doesn't influence whether the compiler knows about a package or a class within the package; it only allows programmers to use the simple name for convenience.

Comment: Thanks for answering it, but I am pretty new to JAVA enum, I wonder how Java knows what a STRING enum type stands for, if there are multiple enum type defined with name STRING?

Comment: The compiler knows what the type of the case labels must be from the type of the expression at the top of the switch statement.  It sees `cell.getCellTypeEnum()` and knows that the type is `CellType`.  It is an enum, so it enforces that all case labels must be enum constants of that enum type.